# HTML não carrega estilo de font localizado em pastas remotas

Tags: html, css, css-font-face

O arquivo `index.html` está no **localhost**, mas a `font` e o arquivo `.css` está em um **servidor remoto**:

**Este é o link da fonte:**

https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.ttf

### O que já tentei?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaBold';
    src: url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.eot');
    src: url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net/fonts/ProximaNovaBold.svg#ProximaNovaBold') format('svg');
}
body, html{font-family: 'ProximaNovaBold'!important;}
```

> UPDATE: A FONTE **SOMENTE** FUNCIONA SE O ARQUIVO `index.html` estiver no mesmo domínio da font ou seja...Não funciona para `localhost` também, mas somente se estiver no domínio `https://ssl-177586.kinghost.net`.

### PERGUNTA:

Como contornar o problema de index. html não carregar arquivo de font de pastas remotas? O estranho é que somente as fonts não são carregadas, mas imagens e qualquer outro arquivo são.

Comment: Alguém pra ajudar?

Comment: vou ver aqui o que pode ser

Comment: salvem-me plisssss

Comment: camarada seu código está certo, só dê um espaço antes do !important. Você não consegue usar essa fonte porque ela está sendo de fato bloqueada. Vou ver se tem algum jeito de você usar sem baixa-la

Comment: Deve ser algum tipo de "política de privacidade" no qual o detentor da fonte a bloqueia para que a mesma não seja usada.

Comment: Lollipop ela não pode estar em outra pasta?

Comment: Pode. em qualquer pasta. Eu quero aprender a utiliza-la e saber porque não consigo nesse caso.

Comment: O motivo é que o código do arquivo `index.html` é colocado dentro de um editor de texto para a geração de abas para face book. Então tudo deve ser externo: imagens, fontes, etc...

Comment: Não estar no mesmo local é diferente de não estar no mesmo domínio, você precisa que esteja em um domínio diferente ou pode ser simplesmente em uma pasta separada no mesmo domínio?

Comment: Sobre o problema após edição, pode ser por algum bloqueio no servidor. Tanto o seu (local) como o online. Já passei por isso.

Comment: Tem algum feedback ?

Comment: Está na pergunta. Como update.

Answer (score -2):

Baixa a Fonte em `ttf`, vai nesse site: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator, clique em Upload, selecione o arquivo `ttf`. Depois clique na opção **expert**, escolhe quais os tipos de fonte quer: `ttf`, `eot`, `eotcompressed`, `woff`e `svg` são os mais usados. Aceite os termos como última opção e clique no botão para gerar as fontes.

Vai ser gerado também um arquivo `css`.

Coloque as fontes numa pasta, e depois arrume o `css` que gerar com o caminho correto. Depois é só chamá-la em minúsculo:

`font-family: "proxima_novabold";`

Além disso no CSS coloque o tipo dela:

```
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

---

@Lollipop - Para você criar uma aba no Facebook com uma página você tem que ter um domínio `https`, correto ?

Esse domínio está hospedado num servidor. No FTP sua árvore de pastas pode estar assim:

```
index.html
-- css
      main.css
   -- fonts
          proximanovabold.ttf
          proximanovabold.eot
          proximanovabold.svg
          proximanovabold.woff
```

No arquivo **.css** você coloca o `font-face`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_novabold';
    src: url('css/fonts/proximanovabold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/proximanovabold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('css/fonts/proximanovabold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('css/fonts/proximanovabold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('css/fonts/proximanovabold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Desta forma acima tudo está no mesmo servidor. É pra funcionar sim, como te disse eu já fiz isso. Não fiz nada diferente do que te falei.

Você não pode baixar a fonte e colocá-la no servidor ? Qual a dificuldade ?

Você viu o cache da página no Facebook ?

Comment: Já fiz isso e não funciona. Ele carrega a fonte, mas não se aplica no html.

Comment: Impossível. Veja no Inspect Element se está encontrando a fonte. Se não vai dar erro 404 de fonte não encontrada.

Comment: A sua pergunta é somente sobre como gerar a fonte, mas não sobre como carrega-la de uma pasta externa. Der exemplos de links.

Comment: Isso é carregar de uma pasta externa, tanto o seu como o meu código faz a mesma coisa. A única diferença é que seu externo é em outro domínio.

Comment: Olha o print que dei na edição da pergunta.

Comment: Viu o print? Não há erro 404.

Comment: Nada ainda :(((

Comment: Eu já fiz isso, funciona fonte baixada sim.

Comment: manda o link da fonte que vc hospedou.  
E os atributos css. poe na resposta tudo isso.

Comment: Descobri o motivo, mas nao sei como contorna-lo

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta